# Как добавить строку, введенную пользователем, в строковый массив

Tags: c#

Я недавно начал изучать программирование, и не понимаю в как уже имеющийся массив строк добавить еще одну строку, введенную юзером. Хотел бы увидеть решение без использования List

```
        string[] teachers = { "1", "2", "3" };
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        string ye = Console.ReadLine();
        Resize(ref teachers, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < teachers.Length; i++)
        {

        }
        --------------------
Console.WriteLine("введи учителя");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();
                        Array.Resize(ref teachers, 10);
                        teachers[9] = name;  
                        for (int i = 0; i < teachers.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(teachers[i]);
                        }
```

получилось. но как сделать так, что бы значение name присваивалось в пустой индекс после заполненного
то есть, есть 8 имён учителя, а размер массива условно 15
нужно так, чтобы когда юзер ввёл имя, то оно записалось в 9 значение, потом в этот по-новому заполненный массив с новым учителем юзер захочет ввести еще одного учителя,  то значение запишется в 10, и так далее.

Comment: Наконец вы осознали свой косяк и сделали правильно, правда вам опять же, уже написали внятно что и как надо было делать в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1473465/220553) (дам [скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pejz.png) на всякий), зачем удаляли и задавали по новой я не знаю, ведь вы в любой момент можете отредактировать свой вопрос. В любом случае - массивы нельзя дополнять, только пересоздавать по новой, с новым размером. Если вам нужен функционал добавления, то лучше подумайте об использовании коллекций, они для этого и созданы.

Comment: [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Вы просто изменили вопрос на совсем другой, я в эти игры не играю и переписывать ответ каждый раз, когда вам захотелось чего-то нового не планировал. Успехов!

Comment: @aepot я бы отметил ваш ответ как правильный, но вы почему-то обидевшись, удалили

Comment: Я удалил потому что он не отвечает на актуальную версию вашего вопроса.

Comment: @aepot давайте я изменю, и отмечу ваш как правльный, если хотите

Comment: @aepot что бы не просто атк потеряли время

Comment: Нет необходимости. Вы просите сделать некое подобие списка, но без списка. Зачем?

Comment: @aepot у меня все получилось, крмое того как заносить введенный элемент в пустое пространство массива, если вы конечно про код речь ведете. а list я не использую потому что мне непонятна эта тема, а времени на решение мало, хотел бы что бы решение было понятным для меня

Comment: `List<T>` - то же самое что массив `T[]`, только вместо `Length` у него `Count`. Создать новый `List<string> teachers = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };`, добавить элемент `teachers.Add("4");`, всё остальное как с массивом. Попробуйте, никаких ресайзов не надо.